# Javascript Validation Not Working On Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to validate a form using java script on click function i.e during form submit and if condition removed the i am getting the alert message but the alert message should be shown in if condition i.e when the form is empty

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){
     var name = $().val("#name");
     var email = $().val("#email");
     if(name == '' || email == ''){
     alert("test");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email">
<button id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('#name').val()`

Comment: You've misunderstood how to use `.val()`. Always check the console - it's singing errors at you. Also, don't catch form submission on click events; use the dedicated submit event, because you can't suppress submission if you're listening in on click.

Comment: what is the disadvantages of getting form data on click and how to use the dedicated submit event

Comment: Submit event: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){
     var name = $("#name").val();
     var email = $("#email").val();
     if(name == '' || email == ''){
     alert("test");
      return false;
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, input values are retrieved with `$(element).val()`. Your variables should look like this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the input elements you want to get the values from.
Replace

```
var name = $().val("#name");
var email = $().val("#email");
```

with

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
```